# Android TCP Connection on Main Thread or Asynch Task

Tags: android, multithreading, sockets

I am creating application for chat on android , for that one service is running in background in which i am opening TCP connection without an Asynch Task as connection should be always alive till the service is running .
As service is running on main thread and also tcp connection on the same thread will it slow down my application and what is the best way for keeping tcp connection alive in service till service is running?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you setup your connection in the service & then bind it every time you enter a new activity. You can use broadcast manager to receive messages from the service, or implement one of its methods. As soon as your service has began, it shouldn't stop unless there's an issue. You can simply put your a sync task in the service, you just need to rebind it to your new activities if you want to do something with it, e.g send a message.

Comment: please look here http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html
A service runs in the main thread of its hosting process

Comment: You're correct Ganesh, sorry. I've just always ran asynchronous tasks on the service so never noticed

Comment: Updated answer, it doesn't really make a difference to your case